# Transforming values from react template for further use in states

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This might be a duplicate question but I still couldn't find an answer. I am new to react and is struggling to create a login page. I am trying t set states with the values I have just entered in the application for further usage. Using these values I will be making a backed call for authentication.

My React Code

```
import React from "react";
// core components are added   

class LoginPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // we use this to make the card to appear after the page has been rendered
    this.state = {
      cardAnimaton: "cardHidden"
    };
  }

  handleSubmit() {
    console.log(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    console.log(event)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // we add a hidden class to the card and after 700 ms we delete it and the transition appears
    setTimeout(
      function() {
        this.setState({ cardAnimaton: "" });
      }.bind(this),
      700
    );


  }
  render() {
    const { classes, ...rest } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
          <div className={classes.container}>
            <GridContainer justify="center">
              <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>
                <Card className={classes[this.state.cardAnimaton]}>
                  <form className={classes.form} onSubmit = {this.handleSubmit}>
                    <CardHeader color="primary" className={classes.cardHeader}>
                      <h4>Login</h4>
                    </CardHeader>
                    <CardBody>
                      <CustomInput
                        labelText="Email..."
                        id="email"
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        value = {this.state.email}
                        formControlProps={{
                          fullWidth: true
                        }}
                        inputProps={{
                          type: "email",
                          endAdornment: (
                            <InputAdornment position="end">
                              <Email className={classes.inputIconsColor} />
                            </InputAdornment>
                          )
                        }}
                      />

                    </CardBody>
                    <CardFooter className={classes.cardFooter}>
                      <Button  color="primary" size="lg" type="submit">
                        Login
                      </Button>
                    </CardFooter>
                  </form>
                </Card>
              </GridItem>
            </GridContainer>
          </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
export default withStyles(loginPageStyle)(LoginPage);
```

I am trying to send values from my HTML to state in handleChange but it is not reacting whenever I make a change. 
If it something with states, please let me know. I am using a custom theme and hope that the issue is in my implementation and have nothing to do with the theme.

Custom Input Component

```
import React from "react";
// nodejs library to set properties for components
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
// nodejs library that concatenates classes
import classNames from "classnames";
// @material-ui/core components
import withStyles from "@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import Input from "@material-ui/core/Input";

import customInputStyle from "assets/jss/material-kit-react/components/customInputStyle.jsx";

function CustomInput({ ...props }) {
  const {
    classes,
    formControlProps,
    labelText,
    id,
    labelProps,
    inputProps,
    error,
    white,
    inputRootCustomClasses,
    success
  } = props;

  const labelClasses = classNames({
    [" " + classes.labelRootError]: error,
    [" " + classes.labelRootSuccess]: success && !error
  });
  const underlineClasses = classNames({
    [classes.underlineError]: error,
    [classes.underlineSuccess]: success && !error,
    [classes.underline]: true,
    [classes.whiteUnderline]: white
  });
  const marginTop = classNames({
    [inputRootCustomClasses]: inputRootCustomClasses !== undefined
  });
  const inputClasses = classNames({
    [classes.input]: true,
    [classes.whiteInput]: white
  });
  var formControlClasses;
  if (formControlProps !== undefined) {
    formControlClasses = classNames(
      formControlProps.className,
      classes.formControl
    );
  } else {
    formControlClasses = classes.formControl;
  }
  return (
    <FormControl {...formControlProps} className={formControlClasses}>
      {labelText !== undefined ? (
        <InputLabel
          className={classes.labelRoot + " " + labelClasses}
          htmlFor={id}
          {...labelProps}
        >
          {labelText}
        </InputLabel>
      ) : null}
      <Input
        classes={{
          input: inputClasses,
          root: marginTop,
          disabled: classes.disabled,
          underline: underlineClasses
        }}
        id={id}
        {...inputProps}
      />
    </FormControl>
  );
}

CustomInput.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  labelText: PropTypes.node,
  labelProps: PropTypes.object,
  id: PropTypes.string,
  inputProps: PropTypes.object,
  formControlProps: PropTypes.object,
  inputRootCustomClasses: PropTypes.string,
  error: PropTypes.bool,
  success: PropTypes.bool,
  white: PropTypes.bool
};

export default withStyles(customInputStyle)(CustomInput);
```

Comment: I guess its because of you are not initializing input state properly. in constructor itself initialize email to empty string. `this.state = {cardAnimation: "cardHidden", email: "" }`

Comment: Can you also show us the CustomInput component, error might be with it

Comment: @Ashish Already did that with no success.

Comment: @KenanBalija  Added now

Comment: @ShahRukhK Your Input in CustomInput is not having `value` and `onChange` attribute. You are passing it but not using it. I mean your Input should have `value={this.props.value}` and `onChange={this.props.onChange}`